# Displaying Image From Relative Image URL Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

I have taken the route of uploading the file to the file system, and persisting the file path, in the database.

I have successfully uploaded an image file to ("~/Content/images" + fileName) via the

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images" + 
fileName));
```

And I have successfully persisted the file path to the database.

```
auction.ImageURL = path;
```

But the image is not rendering, and upon inspection the image source url is reflecting the absolute path to the image

```
C:\Users\cmazzochi81\Documents\Visual Studio\2015\Projects\MyAuctionApp\Content\images
```

What is going on?

**The Controller -**

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Models.Auction auction, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                                       Server.MapPath("~/Content/images" + fileName));

                // file is uploaded
                file.SaveAs(path);
                var db = new AuctionsDataContext();
                auction.ImageURL = path;
                db.Auctions.Add(auction);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }

        }
        return Create();  
    }
```

**The Model**

```
[DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
[Display(Name = "image URL")]
public string ImageURL { get; set; }
```

**The View -**

```
<img src="@auction.ImageURL" title="@auction.Title" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Server.MapPath` returns the physical directory of the provided virtual path. If you're looking for the virutal path of the folder that can be used in a `img src` attribute, you'll want to use `VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute`.

Since it sounds like you want to save the file (thus needing the physical path) and return a link to the file (thus needing the virtual path), you'll need to use both.

```
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string savePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images"), fileName);
            string url =  System.IO.Path.Combine(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/images"), fileName);

            // file is uploaded
            file.SaveAs(savePath);
            var db = new AuctionsDataContext();
            auction.ImageURL = url;
            db.Auctions.Add(auction);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

Comment: Thanks John for taking the time.  This isn't working.  
What I need to do is save the relative path of the file to the database. 
The absolute path is being saved now.  When I edit the path in the browser developer tools from: 

    C:\Users\cmazzochi81\Documents\Visual Studio 
    2015\Projects\MyAuctionApp\Content\images\chief.jpg

to just src="\Content\images\chief.jpg, the image renders.

Comment: If you're using `VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/images")`, that should return something like `/Content/images` (based on your website settings).  If you're still getting the full path, it sounds like it's still trying to use `Server.MapPath`, which will return the physical path of the folder, like this `C:\users\....`.   Can you confirm what `VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute()` is returning?

Comment: It is returning "/Content/images/image.jpg" inspected within the following line-- file.SaveAs(path);  which the debugger is stopping on and reporting the following error: 

"An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Content\images\image.jpg'. "

Comment: So you are wanting to save the file to the images folder as well as return the relative URL for the image?  I'll update my answer so that works.

Comment: Yes I think so.  I need what is stored in the database, to be the relative URL of the image.

Comment: Bingo John.  Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I missed that initially.  Good luck!